# How do I disallow numbers in a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Hello I was writing a Regular Expression (first time in my life I might add) but I just can't figure out how to do what I want. So far, so good since I already allow only Letters and spaces (as long as it's not the first character) now what I'm missing is that I don't want to allow any numbers in between the characters...could anybody help me please?

```
/^[^\s][\sa-zA-Z]+[^\d\W]/
```

Comment: Can you give an example of some valid (and perhaps invalid) input text that you're trying to match?

Comment: Concrete input string and match examples with edge cases are the key to getting good regex help.

Comment: A valid would be "George Adams" invalid would be "G3ord3 72dms" or "G·20! Ad4m$" or any mixture of numbers or any other special characters in between the text.

Comment: Someone please rephrase the title of this question. It is not descriptive.

Comment: @Rob - still misleading - more accurate would be "how do I only allow letters or spaces"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, what you need is:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*$/
```

This matches:

```
^           - start of line
[a-zA-Z]    - any letter
[\sa-zA-Z]* - zero or more letters or spaces
$           - the end of the line
```

If you want to ensure that it also ends in a letter then put another

```
[a-zA-Z]
```

before the `$`.  Note however that the string will then have to contain at least two letters (one at each end) to match.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to allow letters and spaces, then what you have is almost correct:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][\sa-zA-Z]*$/
```

The `$` at the end signifies the end of the string.

*Edited to correct answer, thanks to @Alnitak*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ensure that spaces occur only between words, use this:

```
/^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+)*$/
```